# How to verify Ripple is working?

Tags: ripple

[isup.me](http://isup.com/) is a cool page that checks whether another page is "down for everyone, or just me". Today I found my access to https://ripple.com/client/ and https://ripple.com/graph/ didn't work at all, due to "[network errors](https://github.com/rippleFoundation/ripple-client/issues/249)".

Ripple is p2p, so theoretically it should always be up ... however it's a young project so there might be bugs, and the server code isn't yet open sourced. What's a good way to verify the Ripple network is up, or rather "is Ripple down for everyone, or just me"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really isn't one yet. Currently there is only one access point into the Ripple system open to the public and there's no system monitoring on it that has public access.

Answer (score -2):

There is actually a way:

1. Download this github repo as a zip arhive https://github.com/rippleFoundation/network-viewer
2. Open in your local chrome

Comment: I want a 3rd party service that verifies the problem isn't related to my local setup. How would downloading the network viewer help with this?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question, you just wanted some kind of "show me ripple p2p status" tool, my answer had to do with how to explore the existing ledger.